# date range filter doesnt change collection.length

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i created a `date range filter` and its working now.

But my question is that why doesn't the `displayedCollection.length` change when i filter it ?

like for example there's only one result so the `displayedCollection.length` value will be **1**

**html**

```
 <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Results : {{displayedCollection.length}}</h2>

 <tr ng-repeat="attendance in displayedCollection | dateRange:from:to ">
    <td>{{ attendance.day | date: 'EEEE, MMM d'}}</td>
    <td>{{ attendance.timeIn | date:'h:mm a' }}</td>
    <td>{{ attendance.timeOut | date:'h:mm a'}}</td>
    <td class="text-capitalize">
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ attendance.details }}</td>
    <td>{{ attendance.totalHrs | date:'hh:mm'}} </td>
</tr>
```

**controller**

```
.filter('dateRange', function ($filter) {
  return function (items, fromDate, toDate) {
    var filtered = [];
    if (!fromDate && !toDate) {
      return items;
    }

    var from = Date.parse(fromDate) - 1;
    var to = Date.parse(toDate) + 1;

    items.day = new Date();

    angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
      var itemDayParsed = Date.parse(item.day);

      if (itemDayParsed > from && itemDayParsed < to) {
        filtered.push(item); 
      }
    });
    return filtered;
  };
})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `displayedCollection` remains the same, you should introduce result of filtering: `temp` and it's length value will be exactly, what you expect:

```
<i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Results : {{temp.length}}</h2>

<tr ng-repeat="attendance in (displayedCollection | dateRange:from:to) as temp">
    <td>{{ attendance.day | date: 'EEEE, MMM d'}}</td>
    <td>{{ attendance.timeIn | date:'h:mm a' }}</td>
    <td>{{ attendance.timeOut | date:'h:mm a'}}</td>
    <td class="text-capitalize">
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ attendance.details }}</td>
    <td>{{ attendance.totalHrs | date:'hh:mm'}} </td>
</tr>
```